# No logro mostrar todos los resultados de una consulta

Tags: sql, join

a ver si alguien me puede echar un cable.
Necesito hacer una consulta que me devuelva el stock disponible de un artículo.
Este stock es el resultado de restar las unidades de la tabla **acumuladoStock**, de las unidades de **acumuladoPendiente**.
En **acumuladoPendiente** es posible que no haya ningún registro, pero necesito que me retorne el de acumulado para poder calcular el stock, pero cuando no hay ningún registro en **acumuladoPendiente**, no me devuelve ningún artículo pese a existir en la tabla artículos y **acumuladoStock**.
Os pongo la consulta, a ver si alguien me puede echar un cable por favor, algún JOIN no estoy poniendo bien, pero no sé cuál.
Gracias.

```
SELECT       ac.CodigoAlmacen,ap.CodigoAlmacen, ac.periodo,ar.CodigoEmpresa, ar.CodigoArticulo, ar.MB_DescripcionWeb, ar.MB_DescripcionCorta, ar.PrecioVenta, ar.MB_IndicadorPadreHijo, ar.MB_CodigoArtPadre, ac.UnidadSaldo - ISNULL(ap.PendienteServir, 0) AS stock
FROM            AcumuladoStock AS ac RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                         Articulos AS ar ON ac.CodigoEmpresa = ar.CodigoEmpresa AND ac.CodigoArticulo = ar.CodigoArticulo LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         AcumuladoPendientes AS ap ON ar.CodigoEmpresa = ap.CodigoEmpresa AND ar.CodigoArticulo = ap.CodigoArticulo 
WHERE        (ar.CodigoEmpresa = '1')and (ar.PublicarInternet = 5) and (ac.periodo=99 or ac.periodo is NULL) AND (ac.CodigoAlmacen = 1 OR ac.CodigoAlmacen is NULL)AND (ap.CodigoAlmacen = 1 OR ap.CodigoAlmacen is NULL) AND (ac.Ejercicio = '2020' OR ac.Ejercicio is NULL) AND TRIM(ar.CodigoArticulo) ='LP8075-01'
```

Comment: Probaste con `LEFT OUTER JOIN`?

Comment: Si, mismo resultado .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba de esta manera. Para mayor comodidad prefiero utilizar left join y no right join. Tambien por comodidad utilizo subconsultas con sus respectivos where...

```
SELECT
   ac.CodigoAlmacen,
   ap.CodigoAlmacen,
   ac.periodo,
   ar.CodigoEmpresa,
   ar.CodigoArticulo,
   ar.MB_DescripcionWeb,
   ar.MB_DescripcionCorta,
   ar.PrecioVenta,
   ar.MB_IndicadorPadreHijo,
   ar.MB_CodigoArtPadre,
   ISNULL(ac.UnidadSaldo, 0) - ISNULL(ap.PendienteServir, 0) AS stock 
FROM
   Articulos AS ar 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN
      (
         SELECT
            a.CodigoAlmacen,
            a.periodo,
            a.UnidadSaldo,
            a.CodigoEmpresa,
            a.CodigoArticulo 
         FROM
            AcumuladoStock a 
         WHERE
            a.periodo = 99 
            AND a.CodigoAlmacen = 1 
            AND a.Ejercicio = '2020' 
      )
      ac 
      ON ac.CodigoEmpresa = ar.CodigoEmpresa 
      AND ac.CodigoArticulo = ar.CodigoArticulo 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN
      (
         SELECT
            b.CodigoEmpresa,
            b.CodigoArticulo,
            b.PendienteServir,
            b.CodigoAlmacen 
         FROM
            AcumuladoPendientes b 
         WHERE
            b.CodigoAlmacen = 1 
      )
      ap 
      ON ar.CodigoEmpresa = ap.CodigoEmpresa 
      AND ar.CodigoArticulo = ap.CodigoArticulo 
WHERE
   ar.CodigoEmpresa = '1' 
   AND ar.PublicarInternet = 5 
   AND TRIM(ar.CodigoArticulo) = 'LP8075-01'
```

Comment: Funciona perfecto gracias !